# How to get shipping service name and rates only using USPS PHP API

Tags: php, usps

I have this code connects to USPS API and get detailed response long list of information and then, the servie name and rates.

How can i make the response only for the service name and rates separated from each other by (|) ?

```
<?php
$devurl = "http://Production.ShippingAPIs.com/ShippingAPI.dll";
$puburl = "http://Production.ShippingAPIs.com/ShippingAPI.dll";
$service = "IntlRateV2";
$userid = "xxxxx";
$xml = rawurlencode('<IntlRateV2Request USERID="xxxxx">
<Package ID="1ST">
    <Pounds>15</Pounds>
    <Ounces>0</Ounces>
    <MailType>Package</MailType>
    <ValueOfContents>50</ValueOfContents>
    <Country>Jordan</Country>
    <Container>RECTANGULAR</Container>
    <Size>LARGE</Size>
    <Width>10</Width>
    <Length>15</Length>
    <Height>10</Height>
    <Girth>0</Girth>
    <CommercialFlag>N</CommercialFlag>
    </Package>  
</IntlRateV2Request>');
$request = $devurl . "?API=" . $service . "&xml=" . $xml;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old post , but it may help some one else to find the solutions.

USPS changes their service names recently.
You will get all the updated names from this [API](http://www.walkswithme.net/usps-shipping-api-with-php)

Hope Its helps..

Answer (score 0):

USPS sends response in its predefined format. you have to convert the response into xml and than parse that using a loop to convert into your desired format.

Response includes a number of services varying in cost and delivery time. Here I have converted xml to array using "xml2array" function. You can find it on internet or contact me. After converting into array, we can parse the services.

also visit for more info - http://uspsship.blogspot.in/